# Showing description on mouse move upon a text inside rich textbox

Tags: c#, .net

In `visual studio` **IDE** often we see the feature that suppose we have entered some text in the text area which contain methods and variables and on the mouse move of that text the **IDE** displays hints and comments about the variable or method. Now my question is how it can be achieved on a `RichTextBox`. I was trying to do it with a `RichTextBox` in c# can you provide us any idea about this??

Comment: Just for your knowledge, that is called `Intellisense` :)

Comment: As I know intellisense is not so simple.What i'm saying is just hints and description viewing.Even the turbo c++ clasical blue scren ide have the feature that after selectinga text if we press F1 the hints will be displayed.I just want to do it on mouse hoover of selected text.Is it possible?if yes then how?

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/247564-how-create-intellisense

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5839/DIY-Intellisense

Comment: the second comment is something of interest i will check it deeply..

Comment: Dont go only for the articles which I have posted. instead search on net because now you know the name of the keyword (Intellisense) :)